# AbstractExcelView - read only files

Tags: spring

I am using AbstractExcelView to write a excel spreadsheet. The only problem that we have is Excel is generating a message "This file originated from an Internet location and might be unsafe. Click for more details".
Now, is there any way we can avoid this through the java code to create the excel?
We're using HSSFWorkbook and CreationHelper to create the spreadsheet.

Any tips/ suggestion would be really helpful!

Thanks,
Vineeth